# No Route Matches when trying to Delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails

No route matches [GET] "/comments/10" when trying to delete comments but here are my comments routes:

```
       comments POST   /comments(.:format)                comments#create
    new_comment GET    /comments/new(.:format)            comments#new
   edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format)       comments#edit
        comment PATCH  /comments/:id(.:format)            comments#update
                PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)            comments#update
                DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)            comments#destroy
```

Comment: Show us your view that has the delete link

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't wrong. You don't have a GET route defined. You have a GET route for Editing, but not for just viewing.

```
view_comment GET  /comments/:id(.:format)     comments#view
```

If that isn't the problem you're talking about though it could be that the button for deleting is calling the GET method instead of the DELETE method. Could you post the code for whatever's calling the DELETE method?

The other option is when you do DELETE you're redirecting back to the wrong route.